# Как узнать все селекторы StyleSheet виджетов PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, qss

В официальной документации, как я понял, для виджета `QWidget` были перечислены только 3 селектора:  `background`, `background-clip` и `background-origin`.

Позже, в интернете я увидел ещё селекторы, по типу `border`, `border-width` и тд.

Где можно посмотреть полный список селекторов *PyQt5*?

Comment: Погуглить? `qt qss` -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Style Sheet Syntax - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Qt Style Sheets Reference  - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Qt Style Sheets Examples  -  https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Custom Looks using Qt 4.2 Style Sheets - https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq20-qss.html